# Bind to Window.Current.Bounds.Width in XAML

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a popup control on a LayoutAware page.

What I really want is for the popup to fill the screen.

I think that the solution is to use Window.Current.Bounds.Height/Width to set the respective properties on a grid inside of the popup control.

I do not want to use the code behind file to set these properties. I would like to be able to bind to Window.Current.Bounds.Height in the XAML.

Can I do this?

Is there a better way to make a popup fill the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by writing converters for height and width.

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class HeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add this in your page resources section -

```
    <common:WidthConverter x:Key="wc" />
    <common:HeightConverter x:Key="hc" />
```

Use them for your popup -

```
        <Popup x:Name="myPopup"  >
            <Grid  Background="#FFE5E5E5" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource hc}}" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource wc}}" />
        </Popup>
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. @Typist Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to respond to the page size changing -- Docking to the left or right, or event 2/3 size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use converter (see Typist) 
OR use static class.

In your App.xaml:

```
<datamodel:Foo x:Name="FooClass" />
xmlns:datamodel="using:MyProject.Foo.DataModel"
```

And in your xaml :

```
Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource FooClass}, Path=Width}"
```

Where Width is a property in your class which return Window.Current.Bounds.Width.

Sample : `public double Width{get{return Window.Current.Bounds.Width;}}`

Regards.

Comment: This is a good solution also. If I could see myself using 5 or 6 properties, I would have created a static class instead. @David Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Super. Why wouldn't you change with this solution if it's better ?

Comment: I am using the converters in my project right now as shown above. That is why I marked the alternative answer as the answer. Both your and Typist's answers would work in my case. I am using the MVVM pattern in my application. A third solution would be to put it as a property of my View Model. I did not want to have to replicate it for each View Model.